# How to keep integers grouped together after Infix to Postfix

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation, shunting-yard

I have written an Infix to Postfix method, but I am struggling to figure out how to keep integers together between operators. Currently, all integers put into the method are separated at the end of the method. So 3*15*(45-23) becomes (3, 1, 5, *, 4, 5, 2, 3, -, *) when it should be (3, 15, *, 45, 23, -, *). I just need some tips or pointers in the right direction too figure this problem out. I read something about an abstraction layer but couldn't understand it enough to implement it.

UPDATE
 I got my program to keep integers grouped together but my fix leaves with me numbers being tacked on to the end. My fix involves scanning the next number while it's not empty and if its a number but the current number will then be set as the next number in the next pass of the loop. Should I just try and new solution or can I get this one to work?

````
  StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
                    int j = i;
                    temp.append(numAsString);
                    if (!expression.substring(j+1, j+2).isEmpty())
                    {
                        nextNum = expression.substring(j+1, j+2);
                        while (nextNum.equals("0") || nextNum.equals("1") || nextNum.equals("2")
                            || nextNum.equals("3") || nextNum.equals("4") || nextNum.equals("5") || nextNum.equals("6") || nextNum.equals("7")
                            || nextNum.equals("8") || nextNum.equals("9"))
                        {
                            if (numAsString.equals("π") || nextNum.equals("π")) {
                                temp.append("3.14");
                            }
                            temp.append(nextNum);
                            System.out.println(nextNum);
                            j++;
                            nextNum = expression.substring(j+1, j+2);
                        }
                    }
                    numStack.push(temp.toString());```
````

Comment: You aren't scanning the operands correctly. You need to keep scanning while there is a following digit.

Comment: `expression.substring(j+1, j+2).isEmpty()` will never be true, hence you can remove the condition

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

1. When you detect your first digit, parse it and assign to a
   value `sum`.
2. When you get the subsequent digits, multiply `sum` by `10` and add the digit.
3. Continue doing that until all digits have been processed.  Then store push the
   value on the stack.

If you are working with strings

1. then read in the first digit and assign to a string.
2. Continue reading other digits and concatenating them to the string.
3. When done, push the string on the stack.

Here is an example of the first method.

```java
         String v = "4982 + 2345";
         int value = 0;
         int n = 0;
         while (Character.isDigit(v.charAt(n))) {
            char c = v.charAt(n);
            value = value * 10 + (c - '0'); // Convert digit from ASCII
            n++;
         }
         System.out.println("value = " + value);
```

Prints

> value = 4982

Note that `n` would go out of bounds once it hit the end of the string.  But your main code should take care of that.